Counting of bags
A man has $250$ gold coins. He wants to divide them into bags in such a way that he can pay any amount from $1$ to $250$ by handing over some bags. What should be the minimum number of bags?
(1) $8$
(2) $9$
(3) $10$
(4) $7$
My Attempt : I have seen somewhere that $1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128 = 255$. So answer is $8$. It is just count of summing terms. But I wants to know that Where did this idea come from?

Running guess is that the underlying premise is binary numbers, hence the powers of $2$ being used. I'm not sure how this would ensure minimality though.

(This question has almost certainly be posted to MSE before.) First show that we need at least $ \lceil \log_2 250 \rceil = 8$ bags. Then, we have a pretty natural construction esp by considering binary representation.

Please tell me that Where did idea of binary representation comes from? And you create another doubt that this question linked to logarithm. Please elaborate.

This idea is famous worldwide, and the use of binary is so efficient that, that's the reason why we use base $2$ in computer science.
We can form any number from $1$ to $2^{n}-1$ for $n$ powers of $2$ uniquely, using only sum of the powers of $2$. You can see for yourself that this is not satisfied for any other base. Consider $3$ for example. You just cannot form $2,5$ etc using only sum of powers of $3$. You must subtract and add some powers to get the result. But in the question that means that you have to distribute or remove the coins in some bags, violating the question conditions.
We can summarise why we use powers of $2$ to gain minimality or why it's so efficient to use binary in problems like these.:

We can maximise the range of numbers represented with fewer units (#bags or powers of $2$)

We can avoid redundancy using powers of $2$, since no two combinations of powers of $2$ represent the same number.

Each bag contributes to a number or doesn't, forming a perfect binary system.

Powers of $2$ use only addition to uniquely form numbers unlike other number systems.

You never need to remove / split coins


Then, you can just find the number of bags $\left(\lceil \log_2 250 \rceil = 8  \text{bags} \right)$ or you can find the result as $8$ using your own way which you have done.
Hope this resolves your doubts.

To pay a specific amount, a bag can be selected or not selected ; only $2$ options $0$ or $1$, like in binary numbers, so it is relevant to use numbers like $2^k$.
Imagine another question, where bags can be not selected (factor $=0$), selected (factor $=1$), or selected with a factor $2$ ; we would work with numbers $3^k$.

Powers of 3 also work if both the buyers and sellers have bags of $3^k$ coins. Then (in your notation), a bag may be selected with a factor of -1. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary
